# Uglifying javascript code with grunt-contrib-uglify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have the following file: `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "uglify",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

also the following file: `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            options: {
                beautify: true,
                mangle: {
                    properties: true
                }
            },
            log_sum_9: {
                src: 'log_sum_9.js',
                dest: 'log_sum_9.min.js'
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('log_sum_9', ['uglify:log_sum_9']);
}
```

also the following file: `log_sum_9.js`

```
(function() {
    var
        sum = "2+3+4",
        calc = function(operation) {
            return eval(operation);
        }
    ;
    console.log(calc(sum));
})();
```

Then I do:

to install the required `NodeJS` modules:

```
$ npm install
```

to uglify `log_sum_9.js`:

```
$ grunt log_sum_9
```

then I get the uglified file: `log_sum_9.min.js`:

```
!function() {
    var sum = "2+3+4", calc = function(operation) {
        return eval(operation);
    };
    console.log(calc("2+3+4"));
}();
```

Both scripts works properly:

```
$ node log_sum_9.js
9

$ node log_sum_9.min.js
9
```

My problem is that the uglified file `log_sum_9.min.js` didn't change the names of the variables: `sum`, `calc`, `operation` (all these variables are local variables).

If the content of the file `log_sum_9.js` is introduced on the following online obfuscator: https://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

then you get the following code:

```
var _0x257f = ["\x32\x2B\x33\x2B\x34", "\x6C\x6F\x67"];
(function() {
    var _0xb897x1 = _0x257f[0],
        _0xb897x2 = function(_0xb897x3) {
            return eval(_0xb897x3)
        };
    console[_0x257f[1]](_0xb897x2(_0xb897x1))
})()
```

where as you can see the previous 3 variables: `sum`, `calc`, `operation` has changed their names.

If you put the above code on the file: `log_sum_9.online.js`, then you can do:

```
$ node log_sum_9.online.js
9
```

(it works properly too)

**My question is:**

How do I have to configure the file: `Gruntfile.js` to get the previous 3 variables been obfuscated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify), (as far as I'm aware), doesn't offer the same level of obfuscation as the online tool you linked to in your post - whereby it appears to encode Strings using JavaScript Hexadecimal Escape codes/sequences.

However, [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) utlilizes [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) which provides options for [mangling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js#mangler-options) names. You can set the `mangle` values for both the `toplevel` and `eval` properties to `true`.

**Gruntfile.js**

The `options` in your `uglify` Task can be set as follows:

```js
// ...
options: {
    beautify: true,
    mangle: {
        properties: true,
        toplevel: true, // <-- Add this
        eval: true  // <-- Add this
    }
},
// ...
```

**Note:** When mangling names you need to be diligent to ensure your code still function as intended. There *may* be certain names that you don't want to be mangled (e.g. `jQuery` is quite a common one). An excerpt from the `uglify-js` documentation reads:

> When mangling is enabled but you want to prevent certain names from being mangled, you can declare those names with `--mangle reserved` — pass a comma-separated list of names...

To exclude certain names from being mangled in your grunt `uglify` Task you can provide an Array of names using the `reserved` property:

**For example**

The following configuration mangles all names excluding `operation` and `jQuery`:

```js
// ...
options: {
    beautify: true,
    mangle: {
        properties: true,
        toplevel: true,
        eval: true,
        reserved: ['operation', 'jQuery'] // Exclude mangling specific names.
    }
},
// ...
```